# How to remove server header using middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

In ASP.NET Core 1.0 every response will include the header `Server: Kestrel`. I want to remove this header along with other header like `X-Power-By` using middleware.

I know that we can remove Kestrel header in host configuration by setting the following but I want to do it using middleware (actually when we have Httpmodule we can do like this so I am learning same thing). I tried my bit it did not work.

```cs
new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
```

Tried code:

```cs
public class HeaderRemoverMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public HeaderRemoverMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.OnStarting(callback: removeHeaders, state: httpContext);
        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }

    private Task removeHeaders(object context)
    {
        var httpContext = (HttpContext)context;
        if (httpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Server"))
        {
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

public static class HeaderRemoverExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseServerHeaderRemover(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<HeaderRemoverMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The boolean property should work.

Comment: I know it will work but I want to remove all such header from single place.

Comment: new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false) worked for me!

Answer (score 28):

I've verified that this code is working as of Kestrel 1.0.0:

```cs
.UseKestrel(opt => opt.AddServerHeader = false)
```

This removes the `Server: Kestrel` header from the response.

---

If you want to remove other arbitrary headers from the response, a variation of your code will work. This **doesn't** work for the `Server: Kestrel` header, because it appears that Kestrel adds this after the `OnSending` delegate runs.

Here's a sample middleware that will remove any headers you pass to it:

```cs
public class HeaderRemoverMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ImmutableList<string> _headersToRemove;

    public HeaderRemoverMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ImmutableList<string> headersToRemove)
    {
        _next = next;
        _headersToRemove = headersToRemove;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            _headersToRemove.ForEach(header =>
            {
                if (httpContext.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header))
                {
                    httpContext.Response.Headers.Remove(header);
                }
            });

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
}

public static class HeaderRemoverExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseHeaderRemover(this IApplicationBuilder builder, params string[] headersToRemove)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<HeaderRemoverMiddleware>(headersToRemove.ToImmutableList());
    }
}
```

To use it, add it to the very top of your application pipeline:

```cs
app.UseHeaderRemover("Content-Type", "AnotherHeader");
```

Comment: In .NET 6.0, if you don't have `.UseKestrel`, you can use `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(x => x.AddServerHeader = false);`